# WUBI installation can no longer boot, UUID disk not found

Tags: 10.10, wubi, windows-vista

Yesterday my WUBI/Vista installation was working fine. I shut it down at the train station, all good then when I attempted to boot Ubuntu at home I got a message saying the UUID for root could not be found. By booting with the Ubuntu live CD I found that the `C:\ubuntu\disks` folder stat structure was broken, reported as `"??? ??? ??"` kinda thing. I booted into Windows, scheduled a CHKDSK, ran that on boot which found some errors and rebooted. Still no dice.

I am not stressed because it appears my home directory is still there with all my content so I don't mind re-installing the OS (probably will clean it up some).

What is the best path from here to repair the WUBI installation? Is there anything else I should do to repair it? I'm looking at whether the drive is dying now to work out why this occured. Possibly I moved the laptop before shutdown had completed.

Comment: I always say this never install with wubi, never worth the trouble it saves you upfront.

Comment: Old unanswered question and asker unlikely to return, flagging as too localised..